# $PATH variable on Fish Shell OS X

Tags: shell, osx, environment-variables, path, fish

I have somehow screwed up my path variables with Fish shell on OS X.
Is this the proper `$PATH` variable in the `config.fish`?

```
user@host ~> more ~/.config/fish/config.fish
set -g -x PATH /usr/local/bin $PATH
set -g -x fish_greeting 'Welcome to fish shell, Ansel'

user@host ~> more /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin

e202414@TWC-MACS1DF91 ~> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: Is `$fish_user_paths` set?

Comment: `user@host ~> echo $fish_user_paths

/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin`  

thanks so much for helping and for the amazing shell!

Comment: I think this issue came from upgrading my python and not from fish shell. I did `brew reinstall python` and it fixed pip for me.

What is the proper way for me to clean up my $PATH variable in Fish? I have been looking at the $PATH information on the Fish howto but I want to make sure I do it correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: My advice is to set `fish_user_paths` to include those path components that you wish to add to the default `$PATH`. For example, `/bin` is surely in `$PATH` already so it doesn't need to be in `$fish_user_paths`.